# Using a style dictionary and converter in same resources

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a small program that has a converter for the background color of an item based on a boolean value.  I also have a Style Sheet to cover a lot of the basic formatting.  I have both of these working independently, but when I try to out them together as in:

```
UserControl.Resources>
    <converter:RawMaterialHighlight x:Key="RawMat"></converter:RawMaterialHighlight>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I get an 2 errors:

> Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.
>
> All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them. Line 13 Position 10.

When I add x:Key"Dictionary" to the dictionary line, it says that it cannot resolve the dictionary resource

```
<TextBlock Text="Material Type" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TextBlockSectionHeader}"></TextBlock>
```

> The resource "TextBlockSectionHeader" could not be resolved.

if I add Dict.TextBlockSectionHeader I get the same 'could not be resolved' error.  I am assuming that I am declaring it incorrectly in the Resources section, I have so far been unable to find the solution though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Merged dictionaries and local resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625928/merged-dictionaries-and-local-resources)

the answer was to nest the style in a merged dictionary and put the whole thing inside a resource dictionary:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <converter:RawMaterialHighlight x:Key="RawMat"></converter:RawMaterialHighlight>
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</UserControl.Resources>
```